# e/3 argument? Uniform convergence from a topoloical space to a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove that if we take a sequence (say fn) in C(X,Y) that converges uniformly to to a function f: X to Y, then f must be an element of the space C(X,Y). Where f moves from a topology to a metric.
Is this along the lines of an e/3 argument?

Comment: Yes, but instead of finding a corresponding $\delta$, you will choose a suitable neighbourhood $U$ of the point of interest.

Comment: Stuggling still, any more help possible? Im defining (X,t) to be a topological space and (Y,d), with C(X,Y) the space of continuous functions with domain X and codamain Y.

Comment: You need to show that $f$ is continuous at each point $x_0\in X$. So fix such a point, and an $n$ large enough. Now choose a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $d(f_n(x),f_n(x_0))<\varepsilon/3$ for all $x\in U$. Now use the triangle inequality to make this $d(f(x),f(x_0))$.

Comment: Eugh I get it but I cannot get my head round constructing it at all. Don't suppose you could lay out the entire proof for me?? (I beg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $C(X,Y)$ converging uniformly to $f$. We aim to show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$. Let $\varepsilon>0$.

Choose $n_0\in\mathbb N$ large enough so that $d(f_n(x),f(x))<\varepsilon/3$ for all $x\in X$ and all $n\geq n_0$. (We can do this because $f_n\to f$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$.) Fix $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\geq n_0$.

Since $f_n$ is continuous at $x_0$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $d(f_n(x),f_n(x_0))<\varepsilon/3$ for all $x\in U$. Now, for each $x\in U$, we have $d(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$ (these details need filling in). Thus $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is continuous.